# Eliminar contenido con Expresiones Regulares - Regex

Tags: regex

queria realizaros una pregunta de como se puede eliminar un contenido con Expresiones Regulares. Estoy añadiendo esta Expresion regular, pero el problema que tengo es que no sabe en que DIV debe cerrar. Y por tanto se come casi todo mi contenido. Parece que las Expresiones Regulares no son capaces de saber donde deben cortar el DIV.
       **Este seria el contenido HTML:**

```
<div class="aawp">
  <div id="aawp-tb-445">
     <div class="aawp-tb aawp-tb--desktop aawp-tb--cols-5 aawp-tb--hide-labels">
         ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Y lo intento extraer con esta Expresión Regular**, pero como menciono arriba. No sabe donde debe cerrar el DIV correspondiente, por tanto se come todo el contenido HTML.

```
<div class="aawp">(.*?)<\/div>
```

Comment: Lo de dentro siempre serán divs? El nivel de anidación es siempre como el ejemplo? O podrías encontrar cosas como: `<div class="aawp"><div></div><div></div></div>`?

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de @nxnev es adecuada, deberías utilizar un parser HTML. Te evitarás problemas y harás el código más mantenible.

Si por lo que sea quieres seguir adelante con una expresión regular, ten en cuenta que probablemente tendrás limitaciones. En cualquier caso la que te presento debería evitar muchos de estos problemas:

**nota**: solo funcionará para lenguajes compatibles con expresiones regulares PCRE (php, perl, python (módulo `Regex`, no `Re`)

Javascript por ejemplo no es compatible con PCRE

---

**Versión extendida (necesita flag `x`):**

```
(?=<div[ ]class="aawp">)  # El primer div debe ser con clase aawp
(                 # primer grupo (será la base de la recursividad)

  #--- Opciones ---#
  # Cualquier cosa salvo <> una o más veces
    [^<>]+
  # Cualquier etiqueta vacía (void element)
  | <(?=area|base|br|col|embed|hr
       |img|input|link|meta|param|source
       |track|wbr)\w+[^>]*>
  # Comentarios html
  | <!-- .*? -->
  # Cualquier otra etiqueta (puede tener anidación)
  # Recursividad con grupo 1 (?1). El grupo 2 se usa para 
  # cerrar la misma etiqueta original
  | <(\w+)[^>]*>(?1)*</\2>
)
```

**[Demo (con flag 'x')](https://regex101.com/r/AMBU9W/4/)**

---

**La versión compacta (sin flag `x`):**

`(?=<div[ ]class="aawp">)([^<>]+|<(?=area|base|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param|source|track|wbr)\w+[^>]*>|<!--.*?-->|<(\w+)[^>]*>(?1)*</\2>)`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lGa5tv/4/)**

---

Aún así, no están exentas de limitaciones. Por ejemplo, no encontrarían algo así: `<div>hola</di>` o `<div style="no deberia tener un mayor >"></div>` o `<div>></div>`

El primero es fácilmente solucionable cambiando `</\2>` por `</[^>]+>` pero preferí dejarlo tal cual porque no veía correcto considerar etiquetas con distinto nombre como iguales aunque se correspondan con el mismo nivel.

Comment: Buena respuesta.. Un detalle: perl no usa PCRE, tiene su propio motor de regex. PCRE es una librería que se creó independientemente y es **C**ompatible con la sintaxis de **P**erl

Comment: Correctísimo. Por eso puse "compatible con PCRE", en el sentido de indicar que se busque lo soportado en PCRE. En realidad creo que lo único un poco más especial en la expresión regular es la recursividad. De no ser por eso muchos motores de regex podrían ejecutarla. Buen apunte en cualquier caso :-)

Answer (score 0):

Las expresiones regulares no son la herramienta adecuada para este tipo de tareas. No está mal aplicarlas a páginas HTML cuando se trata de situaciones simples y consistentes, pero es muy difícil (y en algunas implementaciones imposible) hacer que una expresión regular pueda lidiar con la complejidad de HTML. Si necesitas hacer este tipo de tareas de manera recurrente y no es seguro que el estilo de marcado sea uniforme, es mejor que uses un verdadero analizador sintáctico (parser). Busca uno en internet, ya sea en forma de biblioteca o herramienta completa, y ahórrate los dolores de cabeza.

Dicho lo anterior, llegué a esta expresión regular que parece hacer el trabajo deseado con ese ejemplo en específico (usando PCRE en GNU `grep`):

```
(?<=\n)?(\s*?)<div class="aawp">\n(?:.|\n)*?\n\1<\/div>(?=\n)?
```

Ejemplo:

```
$ cat file
<div class="foo">
  <div id="aawp-tb-445">
    <div class="aawp-tb aawp-tb--desktop aawp-tb--cols-5 aawp-tb--hide-labels">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bar">
  <div class="aawp">
    <div id="aawp-tb-445">
      <div class="aawp-tb aawp-tb--desktop aawp-tb--cols-5 aawp-tb--hide-labels">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="baz">
  <div id="aawp-tb-445">
    <div class="aawp-tb aawp-tb--desktop aawp-tb--cols-5 aawp-tb--hide-labels">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$ grep -Poz '(?<=\n)?(\s*?)<div class="aawp">\n(?:.|\n)*?\n\1<\/div>(?=\n)?' file
  <div class="aawp">
    <div id="aawp-tb-445">
      <div class="aawp-tb aawp-tb--desktop aawp-tb--cols-5 aawp-tb--hide-labels">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Explicación:

- `(?<=\n)?`: Equivalente a `^`. Busca el salto de línea precedente, si es que existe, pero no lo incluye en el resultado.
- `(\s*?)`: Busca y captura la sangría para referenciarla más tarde.
- `<div class="aawp">`: La etiqueta de apertura correspondiente.
- `\n`: Equivalente a `$`.
- `(?:.|\n)*?`: Similar a `.*?` pero aceptando saltos de línea.
- `\n`: Equivalente a `^`.
- `\1`: Busca el mismo nivel de sangría capturada previamente.
- `<\/div>`: La etiqueta de cierre correspondiente.
- `(?=\n)?`: Equivalente a `$`. Busca el siguiente salto de línea, si es que existe, pero no lo incluye en el resultado.

Toma en cuenta que, dado lo explicado en el primer párrafo, dicho patrón fallaría en casos como estos:

- El nivel de sangría no coincide.
- La clase de la etiqueta cambia.
- El archivo HTML se minimiza para ahorrar espacio.